# How can I remove a CheckBox's borders?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox

I'd like to create a `CheckBox` without borders. It should still display the checkmark when checked.

Comment: Is trickery out of the question? I know it requires additional work but you could create your own control or use a label with no border and a white background and just add/remove a check on the `OnMouseUp` event.

Comment: @AndreiV Pretty sure this will work, though as you said it implies more work (work-around actually). Was hoping for an answer which implied a CheckBox control property or something. Thanks!

Comment: When nothing else works, cheat :). Spor.

Comment: I did as you said: create a custom Label control with no border and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following AndreiV advice, I created a CustomControl which inherited from Label. Next I override the OnPaint and OnClick events to make it look and behave like a CheckBox. In order to display the check box "checked image" I used a bit of paint for cropping it to what I needed.

Below is the full code:

```
public partial class FlatCheckBox : Label
{
    public bool Checked { get; set; }

    public FlatCheckBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Checked = false;
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        Checked = !Checked;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            pevent.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);

            var bigRectangle = new Rectangle(pevent.ClipRectangle.X, pevent.ClipRectangle.Y,
                                             pevent.ClipRectangle.Width, pevent.ClipRectangle.Height);
            var smallRectangle = new Rectangle(pevent.ClipRectangle.X + 1, pevent.ClipRectangle.Y + 1,
                                               pevent.ClipRectangle.Width - 2, pevent.ClipRectangle.Height - 2);

            var b = new SolidBrush(UllinkColors.NEWBLUE);
            var b2 = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

            pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, bigRectangle);
            pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(b2, smallRectangle);

            if (Checked)
            {
                pevent.Graphics.DrawImage(Resources.flatCheckedBox, new Point(3, 3));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class RoundButton : Button
    {

        protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            GraphicsPath grPath = new GraphicsPath();
            grPath.AddEllipse(0, 0, ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
            this.Region = new System.Drawing.Region(grPath);
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
    }

}
```

this is a class that generate a customized round button, can be good starter for you to make your own customCheckbox by doing similarly

Comment: It's a starter but it's not a good starter I think. The OP can't achieve what he wants with this, also I think there is nothing to do with `Region` in this problem, he needs some custom painting.

Comment: @KingKing, the example provides all the knowledge the OP would need to solve their problem. By altering 2 lines I got this to do just what the OP whats.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko you may not understand the actual problem of the OP, he may mean the border of the **square box** around the checkMark, not the border of checkBox itself. Could you post some screen shot of what you achieved?

Comment: @KingKing, you could be right, this is using the example above, http://i40.tinypic.com/slqs85.png

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko the example above uses only `Region` property, how could you set its `Region` so that the Text is still shown while the square box's border is chipped off? unless we use some complex Region which must include both the square box and the Text.

Comment: @KingKing, thats correct, I simply added 2 rectangles. Not really complex.

Answer (score 0):

The verified answer on [this question](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/57349.aspx) states:

> You cannot remove just the border because the check box is drawn by windows and it's pretty much all or nothing.

This is because the System.Windows.CheckBox is a native control.

A workaround to this would be drawing you own CustomCheckBox, with no visible borders.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If by CustomCheckBox you mean a Control that inherits from CheckBox, then this will not work 100%. Even if one overrides the OnPaint event, when holding down the mouse click on the checkBox, the border will become visible. However, another custom Control might just do the trick. Thanks!